# How i can inject a javascript file inside my site collection using pnp-powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, powershell, office-365, pnp-powershell

I want to inject a JavaScript inside my sharepoint online site collection. now i find this command which sound provide the functionality i need `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink` [link](https://sharepointconcepts.com/tag/sharepoint-online/)

but i am not sure how i need to use this function inside my pnp-powershell script. now i wrote the following:-

```
#Credentials to connect to office 365 site collection url 
$url ="https://XXXXX/sites/MainSite/"
$userName ="XXXXXXXX.com" 
$password ="XXXXXXX"

Write-Host "Loading libraries"
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:Common\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$env:Common\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")


Write-Host "Authenticating to SharePoint Online Tenant site $url"
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
#Credentials for the CSOM calls
$pass =  convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $pass) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials 
$Context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10;

$site = $context.Site 
$web = $site.RootWeb  
$Context.Load($web)
$Context.Load($site)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Credentials for the Connect-SPOnline command
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $(convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOnline $web.Url -Credential $cred
Add-SPOJavaScriptLink -Name HomeLink -Url "XXXXXXXX/sites/MainSite/Style%20Library/myjavascript.js" –Scope Site


$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

but the problem i am not sure how i can link the `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink -Name HomeLink -Url "XXXXXXXX/sites/MainSite/Style%20Library/myjavascript.js" –Scope Site` with the current root web ?? as seems the `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink` does not provide any parameter to define the root web url? so can anyone adivce on this please?

**second question**. now in my case i have site collection and 5 sub-sites. so will injecting the JavaScript inside the root web automatically inject it inside the sub-sites?? now i have enabled the publishing features inside the root web but not inside the sub-sites. so i can from the root web apply the master page to all the underlying sub-sites..so will this inject the JavaScript to all the sub-sites? or i have to manually inject the JavaScript to the sub-sites using pnp-powershell as i am trying to do inside the root web ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add-SPOJavaScriptLink` applies to the current context URL (in your case, https://XXXXX/sites/MainSite/)  but you might have to connect using `Connect-PnPOnline` such as `Connect-PnPOnline –Url $url –Credentials (Get-Credential)`.  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: now when i run the above script i got the following 2 errors. `Connect-SPOnline : The term 'Connect-SPOnline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again`. + `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink : The term 'Add-SPOJavaScriptLink' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: Connect-SPOnline and Connect-PnPOnline are not the same thing.  Sounds like you haven't actually installed PNP PowerShell module to your script.  I assume you are using SharePoint online, thus you would need Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.  You would have a much easier time if you read the documentation and try again.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/pnp-powershell-overview

Comment: now i download/install the pnp powershell setup file from the following link https://github.com/SharePoint/pnp-powershell/releases . then i restarted my windows 7 machine. i open the SP online management shell, try running the script but i got the same errors `The term 'Connect-SPOnline' is not recognized` & `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink : The term 'Add-SPOJavaScriptLink' is not recognized` .. while i can run the following command `Connect-PnPOnline ` so i am not sure.. should i use `Connect-PnPOnline` instead of `Connet-SPOnline`??